# Selecting MAX() on a group doesn't return the corresponding sibling columns

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I'm using [MySQL Tutorial's sample database](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sample-database.aspx).

I need to find the sales person with the worst sales (lowest `venta_por_empleado`) and the best sales (highest `venta_por_empleado`) per each `semestre` and `city`. Using [temporary](https://gist.github.com/chepe263/cf8cbaab77fe2278831ce441439201e5) tables I obtain the following result set (`tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre`, a temporary table):

```
| salesRepEmployeeNumber | Nombre_Empleado  | city          | venta_por_empleado | officeCode | orden_year | semestre | periodo |
|------------------------|------------------|---------------|--------------------|------------|------------|----------|---------|
| 1504                   | Barry Jones      | London        | 6719               | 7          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1286                   | Foon Yue Tseng   | NYC           | 5016               | 3          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1323                   | George Vanauf    | NYC           | 6372               | 3          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1702                   | Martin Gerard    | Paris         | 4180               | 4          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1401                   | Pamela Castillo  | Paris         | 8464               | 4          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1370                   | Gerard Hernandez | Paris         | 12021              | 4          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1166                   | Leslie Thompson  | San Francisco | 3587               | 1          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1165                   | Leslie Jennings  | San Francisco | 11208              | 1          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1611                   | Andy Fixter      | Sydney        | 5550               | 6          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1621                   | Mami Nishi       | Tokyo         | 4923               | 5          | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| 1501                   | Larry Bott       | London        | 7776               | 7          | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| 1337                   | Loui Bondur      | Paris         | 6186               | 4          | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| 1188                   | Julie Firrelli   | Boston        | 4227               | 2          | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| 1612                   | Peter Marsh      | Sydney        | 6036               | 6          | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| 1216                   | Steve Patterson  | Boston        | 4876               | 2          | 2020       | 2        | 2020-2  |
```

To find the sales person with the worst sales, I would apply `MIN(venta_por_empleado)` into the table:

```
SELECT 
    Nombre_Empleado,
    city,
    MIN(venta_por_empleado) as venta_por_empleado,
    orden_year,
    semestre,
    periodo
FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre
GROUP BY
    city, periodo
ORDER BY
    periodo ASC, venta_por_empleado DESC;
```

Result:

```
| Nombre_Empleado | city          | venta_por_empleado | orden_year | semestre | periodo |
|-----------------|---------------|--------------------|------------|----------|---------|
| Barry Jones     | London        | 6719               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Foon Yue Tseng  | NYC           | 5016               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Martin Gerard   | Paris         | 4180               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Leslie Thompson | San Francisco | 3587               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Andy Fixter     | Sydney        | 5550               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Mami Nishi      | Tokyo         | 4923               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Larry Bott      | London        | 7776               | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| Loui Bondur     | Paris         | 6186               | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| Julie Firrelli  | Boston        | 4227               | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| Peter Marsh     | Sydney        | 6036               | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| Steve Patterson | Boston        | 4876               | 2020       | 2        | 2020-2  |
```

To find the sales person with the best sales, I would apply `MAX(venta_por_empleado)` into the table:

```
SELECT 
    Nombre_Empleado,
    city,
    MAX(venta_por_empleado) as venta_por_empleado,
    orden_year,
    semestre,
    periodo
FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre
GROUP BY
    city, periodo
ORDER BY
    periodo ASC, venta_por_empleado DESC;
```

```
| Nombre_Empleado | city          | venta_por_empleado | orden_year | semestre | periodo |
|-----------------|---------------|--------------------|------------|----------|---------|
| Barry Jones     | London        | 6719               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Foon Yue Tseng  | NYC           | 6372               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Martin Gerard   | Paris         | 12021              | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Leslie Thompson | San Francisco | 11208              | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Andy Fixter     | Sydney        | 5550               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Mami Nishi      | Tokyo         | 4923               | 2019       | 1        | 2019-1  |
| Larry Bott      | London        | 7776               | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| Loui Bondur     | Paris         | 6186               | 2019       | 2        | 2019-2  |
| Julie Firrelli  | Boston        | 4227               | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| Peter Marsh     | Sydney        | 6036               | 2020       | 1        | 2020-1  |
| Steve Patterson | Boston        | 4876               | 2020       | 2        | 2020-2  |
```

Using MIN() and MAX() it returns the right values for sales' numbers but the names of the sales person associated to those sales' number do not match.

How can I obtain the correct name for the right sales' number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the constraint every table is temporary, I need to create a new temporary table to copy the contents from `tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre` as suggested by Tim.

```
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre_2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre_2
    SELECT * FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre;
```

Then It's possible to obtain the correct MIN and MAX of the first table using a subquery

```
/* MIN or worst sales*/
    SELECT * FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre a WHERE
    a.venta_por_empleado IN 
    (
    SELECT MIN(b.venta_por_empleado) FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre_2 b
    GROUP BY periodo, city
    );
/* MAX or best sales*/
    SELECT * FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre a WHERE
    a.venta_por_empleado IN 
    (
    SELECT MAX(b.venta_por_empleado) FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre_2 b
    GROUP BY periodo, city
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which might both meet your requirements (more or less) and also work given that `tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre` be a temporary table.  We can join your table to a subquery which finds both the minimum and maximum sales figure for each semester and city:

```
SELECT
    t1.salesRepEmployeeNumber,
    t1.Nombre_Empleado,
    t1.city,
    t1.venta_por_empleado,
    t1.officeCode,
    t1.orden_year,
    t1.semestre,
    t1.periodo
FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        city,
        semestre,
        MIN(venta_por_empleado) AS min_venta_por_empleado,
        MAX(venta_por_empleado) AS max_venta_por_empleado
    FROM tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre
    GROUP BY
        city,
        semestre
) t2
    ON t1.city = t2.city AND
       t1.semestre = t2.semestre AND
       t1.venta_por_empleado IN (t2.min_venta_por_empleado, t2.max_venta_por_empleado)
ORDER BY
    t1.semestre,
    t1.periodo,
    t1.venta_por_empleado;
```

Comment: Since it's a temporary table, MySQL won't allow me to use `tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre` two times in the same query.

Comment: @chepe263 I answered that question early this morning, when my brain wasn't fully functioning.  Try the updated version I gave you above, which only requires a single join to a subquery.  Note that there isn't really any way to get the exact output you want without repeating the `tbl_ventas_ciudad_semestre` table at least once.